# Better alternative to use instead of linq contains for finding list of id`s in database table

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have one database table name as:**DrippingPerformer**

Fields:

```
DrippingPerformerId,ActivistId,username
1   11   abc
2   11   abc
3   12   xyz
4   13   lmn
5   14   lmn
```

Table 2:Dripping

```
ActivistId,name

11   rr
12   tt
13   uu
14   pp
```

Now i want to get all DrippingPerformer Whose ActivistId is 11,12,13.

I have created 1 view for this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS
SELECT   dbo.DrippingPerformer.DrippingPerformerId,dbo.DrippingPerformer.ActivistId,                    
FROM dbo.DrippingPerformer INNER JOIN  dbo.Dripping ON dbo.DrippingPerformer.ActivistId = dbo.Dripping.ActivistId
```

Now from this i want to get all DrippingPerformer Whose ActivistId is **11,12,13**.

This is my code:

```
    public IQueryable GetData(string Ids)
            {
//Here id contains 11,12,13.
                   List<int> actions = Ids.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                    var context = new DataContext();
                    var q = from g in context.MyView
                            where
                                actions.Contains((int)g.ActivistId)
                            select g;
                    return q;
            }
```

But here in above query i dont want to use contains.So is there any better alternative than this??

can anybody provide me better alternative than this??

Comment: Your solution looks perfectly fine, and there are several similar questions... what would constitute a "better" alternative for you?

Comment: `Ids.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList()` for the love of Zalgo, use a IEnumerable<int> ids` as the `GetData` parameter.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco:Can you tell me how this part like actions.Contains((int)g.ActivistId) will be transformed in to sql query?

Comment: @Albireo:Can you tell me how this part like actions.Contains((int)g.ActivistId) will be transformed in to sql query?

Comment: Have you read the question elected as "duplicate master"? It's explained.

Comment: `Contains` gets translated to a concatenation of `Or` clauses in sql because Linq-to-sql doesn't contain anything to translate sql `In`. That's why contains is very bad for big collections. If you're really looking for performance, you're best off using an sql-query afaik (possible to execute sql queries within entity framework!)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Comment: @Albireo:Ok i have got you but is there any better way than this that is what i am asking for.I mean for searching this list of id`s in my DrippingPerformer table

Comment: Quoting @PaoloTedesco, *"Your solution looks perfectly fine, and there are several similar questions... **what would constitute a "better" alternative for you?**"*